# Absolute continuity of measures and limits counterexample

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure and $\lambda$ be a signed measure on a $\sigma$- algebra $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $\Omega$.
Than it can be shown that if $\lambda$ is finite, than $$\lambda << \mu \iff \lim_{\mu(A)\to 0}\lambda(A)=0$$

I'm trying to show by counterexample that the theorem doesn't hold when $\lambda$ isn't finite. 
Based on the proof, my hunch is that $$\lambda << \mu \implies \lim_{\mu(A)\to 0}\lambda(A)=0$$ doesn't hold, but I can't find an appropriate counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $((0, 1), \mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Consider $d\mu= dm$ the Lebesgue measure and 
\begin{align}
\nu(A) := \int_A \frac{1}{1-x}\ dm(x)
\end{align}
for all $A\in \mathcal{B}$. Then it's clear that $\nu((0, 1)) = \infty$, i.e. not a finite measure and
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^1_{1-1/n} \frac{1}{1-x}\ dm(x) = \infty  
\end{align}
but
\begin{align}
\mu((1-1/n, 1)) = \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0 \ \ \text{ as } \ \ n\rightarrow \infty. 
\end{align}

Comment: Great answer, thank you ☺